# How to remove text that appeared in the chart?

Tags: r, visualization

Am trying to plot 2 different columns of a time series data type in a single plot, however the year appears which seems to block the view of the chart. How do I remove the year in the chart so that I can see the charts nicely?

[image]
The below code is how i created the chart

```
data('fertil3')
fertil = ts(fertil3, frequency = 1, start = 1913)
plot(x = fertil[,"year"], y = fertil[,"gfr"], type="l", col="red", ylim = c(0, 250), xlab="Time", ylab="")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x = fertil[,"year"], y = fertil[,"pe_1"], type="l", col="blue", ylim = c(0, 250),xlab="Time", ylab="")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the time series object ts to `as.numeric` which then is a vector and can be used to plot it like lines like this:

```r
library(wooldridge)
data('fertil3')
fertil = ts(fertil3, frequency = 1, start = 1913)
plot(x = as.numeric(fertil[,"year"]), y = as.numeric(fertil[,"gfr"]), type="l", col="red", ylim = c(0, 250), xlab="Time", ylab="")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x = as.numeric(fertil[,"year"]), y = as.numeric(fertil[,"pe_1"]), type="l", col="blue", ylim = c(0, 250),xlab="Time", ylab="")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps plot as a base R time series...

Saves a bit of typing too!

```r
library(wooldridge)

plot.ts(fertil[, c("gfr", "pe_1")],  plot.type = "single", col=c("red", "blue"), ylim = c(0, 250), xlab="Time", ylab="" )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>